# Como modificar un registro de tabla producto desde tabla detalle_producto donde se modifique las cantidad de entradas del producto

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

disculpe, alguien podria orientarme con un problema que he tenido al crear una asociacion de tablas ya que he creado dos tablas (producto(codigo_producto,nombre,detalle,existencia); detalle_compra(codigo_compra,codigo_producto,detalle,cantidad)) y al querer registrar una compra en detalle_compra utilizando un codigo_producto ya existente y que a la misma se vaya sumando la cantidad en existencias de la tabla producto siempre y cuando el codigo_producto que se ingrese en detalle_producto sea igual al de la tabla producto pero me sale este error:

```
Error
consulta SQL:
INSERT INTO detalle_compra values(1,2,'peces',5)
MySQL ha dicho:
#1062 - Entrada duplicada '1' para la clave 'PRIMARY'
```

y estoy tratando de hacer ese procedimiento con este codigo:

```
INSERT INTO detalle_compra values(1,2,'peces',5);
UPDATE producto SET producto.codigo_producto=detalle_compra.codigo_producto+1
WHERE producto.codigo_producto=detalle_compra.codigo_producto
```

y lo he modificado muchas veces para lograrlo pero no me queda quizas alguien pueda ayudarme, gracias de antemano !!!

Answer (score 0):

Ese error se produce cuando la clave primaria ya tiene un registro con el valor indicado (Entrada duplicada '1'), en este caso ya tienes un registro con el valor 1 en la clave primaria, que por el orden de los datos de tu insert supongo que es el campo codigo_compra.
Hay 2 soluciones:
- Si tu clave primaria NO es autoincremental o identity intenta esto: INSERT INTO detalle_compra values(2,2,'peces',5). Y cada que insertes un nuevo registro tendrás que cambiar el valor para la clave primaria.
- Si tu clave primaria es autoincremental o identity, entonces omite el primer valor así: INSERT INTO detalle_compra values(2,'peces',5). El valor de la clave primaria se generará en automatico.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero fijate que ahora me sale este error:

Comment: UPDATE producto SET detalle_compra.cantidad=producto.existencias+1
WHERE producto.codigo_producto=detalle_compra.codigo_producto

MySQL ha dicho: Documentación
#1054 - La columna 'producto.codigo_producto' en where clause es desconocida